# Does InnoDB cache keys that does not exist?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb

Consider this example - the table `item` has two columns, `key` and `value`. Data are as follows:

```
> SELECT * FROM item;

 key       value
------------------
  1          a
  2          b
  87         c
```

Suppose we have SELECT queries by random keys between 1 to 100, and the dataset is large. My questions are:

- does InnoDB somehow caches the "missing" keys so that it knows the key such as 3 and 4 do not exists, or must it go to the disk every time?
- will the performance be better if we fill up the remaining key values with dummy records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Innodb stores frequently used pages in memory so it doesn't go to disk on every query. The size of memory buffer is defined in configuration file (usually my.cnf) and the option name is innodb_buffer_pool_size. Innodb files may also be cached by the operating system.

If you have a lot of memory available on the server consider increasing innodb_buffer_pool_size to appropriate value. More information on this: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/03/choosing-innodb_buffer_pool_size/

Inserting dummy records will make it worse - the table will be bigger.

Answer (score 0):

As documented under [The MySQL Query Cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/query-cache.html):

> The query cache stores the text of a [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html) statement together with the corresponding result that was sent to the client. If an identical statement is received later, the server retrieves the results from the query cache rather than parsing and executing the statement again.

Therefore, the cache of `SELECT * FROM item` will only be used if the exact same query is executed again.  Different queries, such as `SELECT * FROM item WHERE key = 3` cannot use the cache of this query (although subsequent invocations of the exact same query would use its own cached result).

Answer (score 0):

Your index will not have a reference to the missing records, so this should not be slower. You could choose to add a primary key index with auto increment to the records and add this to your index (pk, key, value)